# Meteor: session-client-side

Tags: meteor, ionic2, angular2-meteor

So im trying to build ontop of [the angular-meteor WhatsApp clone tutorial using Ionic 2 CLI](https://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/whatsapp2/ionic/setup)

This tutorial basically deletes the `client` folder in the meteor project and uses the [meteor-client-side package](https://github.com/idanwe/meteor-client-side) inside an ionic project to connect to the meteor server.

Which works perfectly fine, but now i'd like to subscribe to a meteor publication with an reactive parameter.

After searching the Meteor API Documentation I found the [Session](https://docs.meteor.com/api/session.html) object:

> Session provides a global object on the client that you can use to
>   store an arbitrary set of key-value pairs. Use it to store things like
>   the currently selected item in a list.
>
> What’s special about Session is that it’s reactive. If you
>   call `Session.get("currentList")` from inside a template, the template
>   will automatically be rerendered whenever 
>   `Session.set("currentList", x)` is called.

In the [Meteor Subscribe Documentation](https://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html#Meteor-subscribe) you can find the following example:

> ```
> Tracker.autorun(function () {
>
> Meteor.subscribe("chat", {room: Session.get("current-room")});
>
> Meteor.subscribe("privateMessages");
>
> });
> ```
>
> This subscribes you to the chat messages in the current room and to
>   your private messages. When you change rooms by
>   calling Session.set("current-room", "new-room"), Meteor will subscribe
>   to the new room’s chat messages, unsubscribe from the original room’s
>   chat messages, and continue to stay subscribed to your private
>   messages.

Which is exactly what I want to do too. But as [the Session documentation](https://docs.meteor.com/api/session.html) states, session is a package I have to add to the meteor project:

> To add Session to your application, run this command in your terminal:
>
> ```
> meteor add session
> ```

Now my question, is there any way to add session to the meteor-client-side packages?

If I just try to call `Session.set()` it fails on runtime with `Session is not defined`

My guess is that I would need some npm package that extracts the Session functionality (basically a sessions-client-side npm package) like [accounts-base-client-side](https://github.com/idanwe/accounts-base-client-side)

Is there an other way to do this? 
How would I build my own sessions-client-side?

I tried to run `meteor add session` in my meteor project but was not able to find the code for Session anywhere in `.meteor` folder and `npm_modules`.

I also looked into the [meteor GitHub](https://github.com/meteor/meteor) but the Session.js file they have contains [only documentation](http://meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/session/session.js)

Any input how to do something like this would be nice

**Update:**

I've looked into the accounts-base-client-side package and found out that they are autogenerated using a script, so im currently trying to adapt this script to work with Session instead of accounts-base.
You can find my attempt at: https://github.com/AwsmOli/session-client-side

Still work in progress, but i should get it to work soon

**Update 2:**

See my answer, my session-client-side is working now :)

Comment: An alternative may be to use rxjs observables - you already have this library in your project from following that tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating the session-client-side package myself, and its working nicely.

If you need it too, its available on GitHub: 
https://github.com/AwsmOli/session-client-side

and NPM:

```
npm install session-client-side
```

credits to [idanwe](https://github.com/idanwe) who created the client side packages and made it realy easy to adapt his work to work with any meteor package :)

To use it with Ionic 2 Apps:

import it in your entry points (`src/app/main.prod.ts` & `src/app/main.dev.ts`)

```
import 'session-client-side';
```

and now the global Session variable is accessable form anywhere in your app:

```
 Session.set("aCoolNameFormyAwsmChangingObject", myAwsmChangingObject);
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Nice work!  MDG is slowly unbundling Meteor, and releasing individual components as NPM modules, so one day you may be able to do this with official MDG released packages.

Answer (score 1):

The "Session" variable should just appear and be accessible. If you need to verify that, start a new project add the package and write some code to access it. It is likely that something has (unwittingly) nuked the Session variable - I have seen this before with another package.

Another way of doing this is with "getReactively". Below is a helper that uses it in a query. Make sure you declare it before the helper (otherwise it won't work). This one uses the result of another helper, but it can be any variable, and you just assign the variable for the reactivity to kick in and run the helper.

```js
this.helpers({
  currentUser: () => { return Meteor.user() },
  elder: () => {
    let e = Elders.findOne({_id: this.getReactively('this.currentUser._id')});
    if (e) {
      utils.services.setupElder(e);
    }
    return e;
  }
});
```

Comment: On looking into getReactivley, it looks like it is part of the angular-meteor package, which works with angular 1, i cant find it in the documentation of angular2-meteor :(

Comment: What should add the Session variable to my client? The only meteor things i have in there are: meteor-client-side, accounts-base-client-side and accounts-email-client-side. I could install angular2-meteor, but according to the documentation, there is nothing i need in there. The 'regular' Meteor client is not accessible with the project setup the whatsapp tutorial suggests - now im thinking about switching to the MeteorCLI version...

Answer (score 1):

As per the [meteor docs](https://docs.meteor.com/api/session.html), you have to import it:

`import { Session } from 'meteor/session'`

This will enable it on the client.

In earlier meteor versions this was not required, as it was both a default package, and automatically imported into the global namespace.

Comment: If i try to import it, my VS Code resolves the import with the ´node_modules/meteor-typings/1.3/test/main.d.ts´ in my meteor project. But on runtime it failes with: ´Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "meteor/session"´

Comment: meteor packages do not resolve to `/node_modules`.   Meteor has a global package cache you can find at `~/.meteor/packages`, but you don't need to worry about this - as long as you add the package (`meteor add session`), which adds it to `/.meteor/packages`, the meteor build tool will do the rest.

Comment: But thats exactly the problem, i do not use Meteor CLI to build my Client, i have a project for the Server thats built with Meteor CLI and a separate Project with the client which accesses the Server using the meteor-client-side npm packages. So im building my app using Ionic CLI hence non of the standard meteor packages which are available to the client. Look at the Whatsapp tutorial ive posted on step 3.